# When I call this recursive function with --> multiply( [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ] , 3 ) , I get NaN. What is the reason behind?

Tags: javascript

When I call this recursive function with --> multiply( [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ] , 3 ) , I get NaN. What is the reason behind?

```js
let multiply = function (arr, num) {
    if (num <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return arr[num - 1] * multiply([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], num - 1);
}
console.log(multiply( [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ] , 3 ));
```

Comment: `num` may be `0`, as you only check `num < 0`, but `num - 1` then isn't a valid array index.

Comment: You want to slice the array rather than pass [1,2,3,4] in the recursive call.

Comment: Also, please learn how to use a debugger. It would show you this faster than writing a question, and you'll need to be able to operate one earlier or later anyways, when more complex issues arise (which happens to everyone).

Comment: @Andreas Modifying the input list seems like a bad idea for a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the last call where `num = 0` you are trying to access `arr[num-1]` which is  `arr[0-1] => arr[-1] = undefined`. Hence all the result becomes NaN.

You need to write the method in following way,

```js
let multiply = function (arr, num) {
   
    if (num < 0) {
        return 1;
    }
   
    return arr[num] * multiply([1, 2, 3, 4], num - 1);
}

console.log(multiply( [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ] , 3 ));
```

Or,

```js
let multiply = function (arr, num) {
   
    if (num < 1) {
        return 1;
    }
   
    return arr[num - 1] * multiply([1, 2, 3, 4], num - 1);
}

console.log(multiply( [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ] , 4 )); // In this case you have add +1 to the num you want because we are never using arr[num] for the first call.
```

Comment: You can use `arr[num - 1]`, but in the `if`, statement you have to do `num < 1`